# Error 'Can't set headers after they are sent' only on Cloud9

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io, cloud9-ide

I am getting following error while using Express and socket.io together on Cloud9 ide:

```
http.js:707
    throw new Error('Can\'t set headers after they are sent.'); ^ Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
    at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage.setHeader (http.js:707:11)
    at ServerResponse.res.setHeader (/var/lib/stickshift/523075494382ec51c3000001/app-root/data/610464/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/patch.js:59:22)
    at next (/var/lib/stickshift/523075494382ec51c3000001/app-root/data/610464/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/proto.js:153:13)
    at Function.app.handle (/var/lib/stickshift/523075494382ec51c3000001/app-root/data/610464/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/proto.js:198:3)
    at Server.app (/var/lib/stickshift/523075494382ec51c3000001/app-root/data/610464/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/connect.js:65:37)
    at Manager.handleRequest (/var/lib/stickshift/523075494382ec51c3000001/app-root/data/610464/node_modules/socket.io/lib/manager.js:564:28)
    at Server. (/var/lib/stickshift/523075494382ec51c3000001/app-root/data/610464/node_modules/socket.io/lib/manager.js:118:10)
    at Server.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:117:20)
    at HTTPParser.parser.onIncoming (http.js:2056:12)
    at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete [as onHeadersComplete] (http.js:120:23)
```

Below is my server.js code:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express()
  , http = require('http')
  , server = http.createServer(app)
  , io = require('socket.io').listen(server);


server.listen(process.env.PORT, process.env.IP);

app.get('/', function(req,res) {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
    res.write('Hello World\n');
})
```

I am using node: "0.10.x", socket.io: "0.9.14" and express: "3.x". This error is coming only on Cloud9 ide. On localhost it runs fine.
Please help.

Comment: It works fine for me: https://c9.io/fardjad/node_version_test

Comment: This happens when try to write into or modify header of a response after it has been sent.

Comment: @fardjad, I have the same code as you in server.js and same package.json file, but I am still getting this error. What node version you are using? When i try to access the app in brower, I get the output 'Hello World', but after that the error occurs which you can see in the Output console of cloud9 ide.

Comment: `process.version` in my **c9** workspace is `v0.10.15`.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this exact same problem. Although it's not a good solution, reverting Express back to version 3.1.0 solved this for me. It appears at a high level that the latest versions of Express and Socket.io don't play nicely together.

The versions I am using after reverting are:

Node: **0.10.x**,

Socket.io: **0.9.16**,

Express: **3.1.0**